# How do you keep TwitterBootstrap's navbar fixed on top of the screen for applications with very long vertical page layouts?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, initializr

I downloaded the bootstrap template from http://www.initializr.com/ 
My question is how do I keep the navbar fixed on top of the screen whenever I scroll down to the footer of my web page?  To have a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve I made a screenshot.

example : **On a mobile device perspective the NAVBAR is fixed**

[image: NAVBAR IS FIXED ON TOP OF THE SCREEN]

example : **When I scroll down to the footer of the page I want the NAVBAR to stay fixed on top of the screen.  As you can see the NAVBAR fails to stay fixed on top of the screen.**

[image]

CODE:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </a>
                    <a class="brand" href="#"><img src="img/pldttranssmall.png"></a>
                    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#about">About</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#product">Product and Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#investor">Investor Relations</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#support">Get Support</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form pull-right">
                            <input class="span2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                                <i class="icon-search icon-black"></i>Go
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**How do I achieve this?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just wrap the navigation bar inside a div and add these css classes to it style it as `class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/Uy5tt/show/

P.S: remove show from the end of the url to see the html

Update: Basically this is what they apply to the div to make it fixed on the top.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it still does not stay visible on top of the screen.  I need it to stay visible on top of the screen even if I scroll way down to the footer.  I've also updated my question and included the code for the navbar.  Thanks

Comment: I was suppose to but your fiddle is almost the same with my code.  How do I modify your fiddle so that the navbar would stay visible on top of the screen even if we scroll all the way down to the bottom of the page.  I dont want it just to stay on top of the page, I want it to stay on top of the screen visible at all times.

Comment: i did nbot get you. i am seeing the navbar fixed on top when i `show` my fiddle.

Comment: when i scroll your fiddle to the bottom of the page the navbar is no longer visible.  It has to be visible even if you reached the bottom of the page.

Comment: which browser are you using. i repeat that if you click on the url above you could see that i have created a fixed header. dont check it in fiddle. it will scrol in the fiddle. view the page in the link i have given you. ok? if problem persists just let me know your browser...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18631/discussion-between-royjavelosa-and-naveen)

Comment: your image cleared out things for me. this is exactly what i told you not to do. :) i asked you to not to view the fiddle, but to use the URL i have put in the answer [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/Uy5tt/show/). this url is the view of the output rendered by the fiddle ok? check this out and tell me what happens...

Comment: Sir finally its working!  Your css did the job
The only problem I have now is that when I minimize or resize my browser to mimic a mobile device, the logo is partially cut from the screen from the left by about 5 pixels.  Other than that this is the solution I was looking for! Thanks for not giving up on my question.